# filtering query data from yahoo finance

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently using the built in web query feature in excel to pull historical stock prices from yahoo finance. the table i receive looks like the one here: http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=SPY+Historical+Prices. my problem is dividends show up in the time series and severely hamper my ability to work with the data. can anyone think of way of truly filtering these? i've tried an autofilter based macro, but this later requires me to use function like aggregate and subtotal, which are limiting. i'm currently working on a function that might be applied to adjusted close prices that when applied to the adjusted close column, spits out filtered results.

thanks for reading!

Comment: assuming adj close prices are in column c, and at dividend days there are two entries, one close price and one blank cell, im thinking something lke this, although this doesn't quite work =IF(COUNTBLANK(C4:C16)>0,C18,IF(ISNUMBER(C17),C17,C18))

Comment: so this actually sort of works, but because the formula doesn't take any sort of dynamic range into account, i get reference errors when I get close to the top (it's trying to read cell that arent on the page). there's an obvious and silly fix to this, but i'd rather do it a bit more elegantly without having to input random stuff in the cells above